# Using @ngrx/entity, how can I update an items array

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngrx-entity

I am using `@ngrx/entity` and this creates a state that looks like the following:

```js
{
   ids: [1, 2, 3],
   entities: [
     1: {id:1, title: "Some title", likes: {count: 1}},
     2: {id:2, title: "Some title", likes: {count: 1}},
     3: {id:3, title: "Some title", likes: {count: 1}}
   ]
}
```

`@ngrx/entity` does give us some cool helpers for updating an item, but it seems (from what I can see in the docs) limited to updating the WHOLE entity only.

However, when a user toggles a 'Like' button, I would like in my reducer to update only that `state.entities[2].likes` property with the response.

Any ideas on how I can go about this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As your state is immutable. You need to update the all entity. @ngrx/entity comes with some helpers that you can use to update 1 entity. In your case, you need to use the updateOne method. https://ngrx.io/guide/entity/adapter

It will look like something like that:

```js
adapter.updateOne(
{
  id: 2,
  changes: {...state.entities[2], likes: value}
},
state
);
```

Comment: May i know How to update Optional Properties In NGrx/Eentity

Comment: You could do it like that:
adapter.updateOne(
{
  id: 2,
  changes: {...state.entities[2], likes: value}
},
{ ...state, property1: value, property2: value }
);

Answer (score 9):

You can make the changes manually as @Remi mention, or you can use the `map` method:

```js
 const newState = adapter.map(
      book =>
        book.title === TheGreatGatsby.title
          ? { ...book, name: 'foo' }
          : book
      state
    );
```